# Update MySQL database using HTML/PHP table (inline)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to update my database using the html/php table with save button to confirm the changes and save in database.

[Here's my Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TDZO.jpg)

How can I edit the 'Quantity' row like text field and save with the button to confirm.

this is my table

```
<table class=" table-responsive table table-striped table-bordered table-hover ">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Item #</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Unit</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <?php
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            $dbName = "db";
            $port = "3306";

            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName, $port);

            if($conn->connect_error)
            {
            die("Connection Failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
            }

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM product";
            $result1 = $conn->query($sql);
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql);

            ?>
            <tbody>

                <?php

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {

        echo "
                <tr>
                    <td>" . $row[0] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row[1] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row[2] . "</td>
                    <td>0</td>

                </tr>";
                }

                ?>
            </tbody>

        </table>
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: Ah, I love a good mystery, *not*. Post your code.

Comment: wait for somebody else then. I'm out.

Comment: i'm sorry sir i'm a new here.. @Fred-ii-

Comment: Did any answers helped you?

Comment: nope. but i found idea [here](http://webslesson.blogspot.com/2016/02/live-table-add-edit-delete-using-ajax-jquery-in-php-mysql.html)

Answer (score 0):

Put your table inside a form.

```
<form action="give_your_action_page" method="post">
    <table class=" table-responsive table table-striped table-bordered table-hover ">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Item #</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Unit</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <?php
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            $dbName = "db";
            $port = "3306";

            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName, $port);

            if($conn->connect_error)
            {
            die("Connection Failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
            }

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM product";
            $result1 = $conn->query($sql);
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql);

            ?>
            <tbody>

                <?php

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {

        echo "
                <tr>
                    <td>" . $row[0] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row[1] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row[2] . "</td>


             <td><input type='number name='".$row[1]."' value='".$row[3]."'/></td>

            </tr>";
            }

            ?>
        </tbody>

    </table>
```

Now at your action page you can access the form values using $_POST array using the value in "Description" field.

For eg : `$_POST["banana"]` will give the quantity of banana.

Update the database using these values.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to change a field that is not in the database?
because

```
<tr>
   <td>" . $row[0] . "</td>
   <td>" . $row[1] . "</td>
   <td>" . $row[2] . "</td>
   <td>0</td>    ---------------->   ? (empty) ?
</tr>
```

You must first create a field called Quantityin your database, then try again if it was a difficult ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok your Code is a really bad , well most of it , and your Q was really hard to understand , but its ok , try to be more accurate next time =) , this answer that i came with is depends on my understanding to what you tried to ask . 
I suggest that you topic from w3shool : [Select data from database](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)

In my answer or in my Code if we can say that , I used [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) , Whats PDO ?

> PDO is an acronym for PHP Data Objects. PDO is a lean, consistent way
>   to access databases. This means developers can write portable code
>   much easier. PDO is not an abstraction layer like PearDB. PDO is a
>   more like a data access layer which uses a unified API (Application
>   Programming Interface).

Search for it on Google and read some info about how it works and try to learn it , its simple and its the same as ( MYSQLI ) .

This is my Code which i tested it many times and it works , this code can be written in many ways but i tried to make it as simple as i can .

```
        <?php
                        // Start of the first part ( connect to the database usnig PDO 
                        $servername = "localhost";
                        $username   = "root";
                        $password   = "";
                        $database  = "your database name";
                        try {
                            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
                            // set the PDO error mode to exception
                            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                            }
                        catch(PDOException $e)
                            {
                                echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
                            }

                       // END of the first part 

                      // second part : bring the new quantity from the field 
                      if(isset($_POST['update']))
                        {
                            $newquantity = $_POST['newQu'];
                    $itemName = $_POST['item'];
                    $UpdateOnQuantity = $conn->prepare( "UPDATE hr SET Quantity = ? WHERE Item = ?");
                    $UpdateOnQuantity->execute(array($newquantity,$itemName));

                        if($UpdateOnQuantity)
                            {


                            }
                            else
                                {
                                    echo "error";

                                }
                }

                $FetchNewQuantity = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM hr");
                $FetchNewQuantity->execute();


?>

<html>  
<head>

</head>

    <body>
        <table class=" table-responsive table table-striped table-bordered table-hover ">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Item #</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Unit</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php 
                while($FetchedData = $FetchNewQuantity->FETCH(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                {
                    ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $FetchedData['Item']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $FetchedData['Description']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $FetchedData['Unit']; ?><td>
                    <td><?php echo $FetchedData['Quantity']; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="test2.php" method="POST">
                            <input type="hidden" name="item" value="<?php echo $FetchedData['Item']; ?>">
                            <input type="text" name="newQu">
                            <input type="submit" name="update">
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code hope it help you , i tested many times as i said so if it did not work with you let me know , and if you did not like PDO just replace PDO code with the normal Mysqli code .

Edit : i edited the code again , did not noticed that you linked your table . i added a while loop so it can show all the data in your table .